# int 111 to binary 111(decimal 7)

Tags: python, binary, int

Problem:Take a number example 37 is (binary 100101).
Count the binary 1s and create a binary like (111) and print the decimal of that binary(7)

```
num = bin(int(input()))
st = str(num)
count=0

for i in st:
    if i == "1":
        count +=1

del st
vt = ""
for i in range(count):
    vt = vt + "1"
vt = int(vt)
print(vt)
```

I am a newbie and stuck here.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide detailed information about your problem and a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Some examples of inputs and expected outputs are always useful. Please, check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question for more details as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend your approach, but to show where you went wrong:

```
num = bin(int(input()))
st = str(num)
count = 0

for i in st:
    if i == "1":
        count += 1

del st
# start the string representation of the binary value correctly
vt = "0b"
for i in range(count):
    vt = vt + "1"
# tell the `int()` function that it should consider the string as a binary number (base 2)
vt = int(vt, 2)
print(vt)
```

Note that the code below does the exact same thing as yours, but a bit more concisely so:

```
ones = bin(int(input())).count('1')
vt = int('0b' + '1' * ones, 2)
print(vt)
```

It uses the standard method `count()` on the string to get the number of ones in `ones` and it uses Python's ability to repeat a string a number of times using the multiplication operator `*`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once you got the required binary.

```
def binaryToDecimal(binary): 
  
binary1 = binary 
decimal, i, n = 0, 0, 0
while(binary != 0): 
    dec = binary % 10
    decimal = decimal + dec * pow(2, i) 
    binary = binary//10
    i += 1
print(decimal)
```

Comment: @YangHG - I Am also new to python. Thank you for the Info

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```
print(int(format(int(input()), 'b').count('1') * '1', 2))
```

Let's break it down, inside out:

```
format(int(input()), 'b')
```

This [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) takes an integer number from the input, and returns a formatted string according to the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec). In this case, the argument `'b'` gives us a binary format.

Then, we have

```
.count('1')
```

This [str method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) returns the total number of occurrences of `'1'` in the string returned by the `format` function.

In Python, you can multiply a string times a number to get the same string repeatedly concatenated n times:

```
x = 'a' * 3
print(x)  # prints 'aaa'
```

Thus, if we take the number returned by the `count` method and multiply it by the string `'1'` we get a string that only contains ones and only the same amount of ones as our original input number in binary. Now, we can express this number in binary by casting it in base 2, like this:

```
int(number_string, 2)
```

So, we have

```
int(format(int(input()), 'b').count('1') * '1', 2)
```

Finally, let's print the whole thing:

```
print(int(format(int(input()), 'b').count('1') * '1', 2))
```